# Trying to write a function to copy subfolders and files of a directory and only the difference

Tags: powershell

```
function Copy-File {
  #.Synopsis
  # copies only the difference of files existing in between source and destination 
  param([object]$source,[object]$destination)
  # create destination if it's not there ...
  mkdir $destination -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  $source1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $source
  $destination1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $destination
  $filediff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $source1 -DifferenceObject $destination1
  $filediff | foreach { 
    $CopyParams = @{ 'Path' = $_.InputObject.FullName }
    if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=') {
      $CopyParams.Destination = $destination1
    } else {
      $CopyParams.Destination = $source1
    }
    Copy-Item @CopyParams
  }
}
```

I want to copy it to LocalAppData in users profile.

Comment: You're looking for [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx).

Comment: `robocopy || headaches`

Answer (score 1):

try just this

```
$destination="c:\tempcopy"
gci "c:\temp" | %{if (!(Test-Path "$destination\$($_.Name)")) {copy-item $_.FullName -Destination "$destination\$($_.Name)" -Force}    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will copy the difference of objects in two folders so that all files not in the first get copied to the second, and vice verse. You could change the destination to a user's Local\AppData folder. Hope this gives you a good starting point.

```
Function Get-Folder($Message)
{

    Function Select-Folder($Title = $Message, $path = 0) {  
        $object = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application   

        $folder = $object.BrowseForFolder(0, $Title, 0, $path)  
        if ($folder -ne $null) {  
            $folder.self.Path  
            $Choice = $folder.Self.Path
        }  
    }  

    Select-Folder -Message $Message -path $env:USERPROFILE

    $selectedFolder = $this

}

Function Start-FolderSelection
{
    $script:firstFolder = Get-Folder -Message "Select the reference folder"
    $script:secondFolder = Get-Folder -Message "Select the folder to compare"
}

Function Compare-FolderContents
{
    $firstFolderChildren = Get-ChildItem $script:firstFolder
    $secondFolderChildren = Get-ChildItem $script:secondFolder

    $script:folderComparison = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $firstFolderChildren -DifferenceObject $secondFolderChildren
}

Function Copy-FileDifferences
{
    $firstFolderDifference = $script:folderComparison | ? { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" }
    $secondFolderDifference = $script:folderComparison | ? { $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" }

    foreach($difference in $firstFolderDifference)
    {
        $diffObj = $difference.InputObject
        Copy-Item $diffObj.FullName -Destination $script:firstFolder
    }
        foreach($difference in $secondFolderDifference)
    {
        $diffObj = $difference.InputObject
        Copy-Item $diffObj.FullName -Destination $script:secondFolder
    }
}

Function Run-Functions
{
    Start-FolderSelection
    Compare-FolderContents
    Copy-FileDifferences
}

Run-Functions
```